# intent can not putExtra object of type XMPPTCPConnection

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I read this  interesting post [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android) and found that i should use putExtra to send object to other activities and to receive that using getIntent().getSerializableExtra("name") is necessary. but when i use putExtra it force me to cast the XMPPTCPConection object to (java.io.Serializable).

**the java android code:**

```
  XMPPTCPConnection connection;
  connection=  xmppConnectio.getXMPPConnectio();
  if(connection.equals(null))
  Log.d("","is  null");
  else
  Log.d("","is not null");

  Intent intent=  new Intent(this,chat.class);
  intent.putExtra("connection", (java.io.Serializable) connection);
  startActivity(intent);
```

**but it throws exception**

```
02-21 05:00:44.733    4672-4683/passargad.ehsan D/connected﹕ yes connected successfully :
02-21 05:00:44.733    4672-4672/passargad.ehsan D/﹕ is not null
02-21 05:00:44.733    4672-4672/passargad.ehsan D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-21 05:00:44.733    4672-4672/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
02-21 05:00:44.743    4672-4672/passargad.ehsan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection**
at passargad.ehsan.MainActivity.triger(MainActivity.java:189)
at passargad.ehsan.XMPPConnectio$connectionXMPP.onProgressUpdate(XMPPConnectio.java:125)
at passargad.ehsan.XMPPConnectio$connectionXMPP.onProgressUpdate(XMPPConnectio.java:55)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the interesting part of story is that it was ok for 3 times correct executing. but then it broke.

**thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you had to cast to `Serializable` should have told you the issue right there. I looked up the JavaDoc for `XMPPTCPConnection` and indeed, it does not implement `Serializable`.

Your app is dying at the point where you are trying to cast to `Serializable`, because the class doesn't implement it.  The post you referenced mentioned "letting the custom class implement `Serializable`", and because it was a custom class, the developer could make that change.  With a library class, you don't have that option.

---

You'll need to come up with a strategy to manage the connection, maybe with some kind of static reference (look at using `WeakReference` to avoid leaking the connection).  You'll also have to handle the situation when the `Activity` is recreated (i.e. device rotation) and be able to re-establish the connection if/when you lose the reference to it.

I'm curious what the best solution would be for managing a connection like this.  I don't have direct experience, but perhaps you can peruse some Smack implementations on GitHub to see how other developers have dealt with this issue.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but is there an other way letting me to pass the connection to other activity and getting that in onCreate

Comment: Your best bet would be to take all the parameters for connection -- host, port, service name, etc. -- and put those in the intent for the new activity, which can then create the connection.

Comment: the way you say means in every activity i should connect again. but i want to use the connection which is already connected. i really need this and i have done lots of solutions like serealization , bundle , global, but none of them can be used.

Comment: i changed the scenario which i can send a class with Serializable implemented here is the question. [Parcelable encountered IOException when sending instance of an object to other activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538166/parcelable-encountered-ioexception-when-sending-inistance-of-an-object-to-other)  thank you